# CCnet send a value to App.config through MSBuild

Tags: msbuild, app-config, cruisecontrol.net

Okay guys i am new here so i need a little help.I made automation test in c# for Nunit and i use it for CruiseControl
the CCnet.config:

```
<msbuild>
            <executable>C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe</executable>
            <projectFile>ClassParseMicroData.sln</projectFile>
            <buildArgs> /t:Build </buildArgs>
            <targets>Build</targets>
            <timeout>600</timeout>
            <logger>C:\Program Files (x86)\CruiseControl.NET\server\ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.MsBuild.dll</logger>
</msbuild>

<nunit>
            <path>C:\Program Files (x86)\NUnit 2.6.2\bin\nunit-console.exe</path>
            <assemblies>
            <assembly>D:\SeleniumProject\microdata-csharp\test-class\ClassParseMicroData\ClassParseMicroData\bin\Debug\ClassParseMicroData.dll</assembly>
            </assemblies>
            <timeout>180000</timeout>                   
</nunit>
```

I want to send to MSbuild property for App.config from my test, something like this `<buildArgs> /t:Build /p:link=test </buildArgs>` it will be used in test, the problem is i don't know how to write App.config correctly to send this value. In test i will use like that `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["link"];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have to rewrite the ccnet.config to call a custom MSBuild script. In the custom MSBuild script you can use [MSBuild Community Task](https://github.com/loresoft/msbuildtasks) using the XMLQuery or XMLUpdate task to get the value from the app.config file. Once the value from the app.config is acquired, it can then be passed in the call of the MSBuild to compile the solution file.

For more info on creating custom MSBuild scripts, the book [Inside the Microsoft Build Engine: Using MSBuild and Team Foundation Build](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735645248) is a good guide. Alternatively you can use [MSDN MSBuild reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0k6kkbsd.aspx).